# Stoping users from accessing an ActionResult but allow it to be acessed via Html.Action/RenderPartial code and AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some ActionResults that I don't want an user to be able to directly access but I need to be able to call them from views using `@Html.Action`, `@Html.RenderPartial`, and `AJAX`. I was using the `ChildActionOnly` but if I use that I can't access the page via AJAX. If I remove the `ChildActionOnly` attribute I can call it by AJAX but I can also call it directly by URL which is what I don't want happening. Is this possible to do of do I have to leave the ActionResult opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the public action with a parameter to indicate whether or not the method should be executed like

```
  public ActionResult DoSomething(bool shouldBeExecuted=false)
        {
            if (shouldBeExecuted == false)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("The action is not available");
            }

            ViewBag.Title = "Test Page";

            return View();
        }
```

And when you create a link for the action, just pass the **"true"** as a query string value.

Comment: I presume for an AJAX call I would just add `?shouldBeExectured=true` and I know how to add a parameter when using `@Html.Action` but how do I pass a parameter when using `@Html.RenderPartial()`?